# Error loading some.dll: Unable to load the test container 'e:\some.dll' or one of its dependencies

Tags: visual-studio-2010, pinvoke, mstest

I have a `VS2010` `C#` project, that references a large set of native .dll's (a commercial java runtime). These file are referenced as 'Content' files in the project, since the need to be copied with the project.

The code in these libraries is called using `PInvoke`, there is no assembly reference.

Every time I compile the solution, the Visual Studio testing framework tries to load all the referenced dll files, expecting to find .net assemblies which may contain unit tests. Since the are no .net assemblies, the following exception is thrown:

> Error loading some.dll: Unable to load the test container 'e:\some.dll' or one of its dependencies. If you build your test project assembly as a 64 bit assembly, it cannot be loaded. When you build your test project assembly, select "Any CPU" for the platform. To run your tests in 64 bit mode on a 64 bit processor, you must change your test settings in the Hosts tab to run your tests in a 32 bit process. Error details: **Could not load file or assembly 'file:///e:\some.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.**

This takes a whole lot of time, and I would like to tell Visual Studio to not try to load these files.

How can I tell Visual Studio to stop trying to load these files?

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I got this wrong:
You are including the P/Invoke target binaries in to the VS solution because you want the binaries to be copied over to the target directory when the solution is built.  You want this because the project will execute from the target directory as soon as the VS solution is built. Correct?

Often times VS packages (both default and 3rd party) try to get smart about the solution content and will follow certain triggers (which are difficult to contain and control by ourselves) and load the solution and project content in their own ways.  Fighting the battle in this area has poor ROI than employing a simpler work around (below).

While I can't provide you with an authoritative answer on how to tell VS's test package to not load all binaries, I suggest removing such binaries from the project as 'content' and leave them in your source control where they are today.  Add a post-build task that will copy the said binaries over to the target.  This will still give you the same result as it is working today but, takes those binaries out of reach for the test probes.

Comment: Your analysis is correct. I must however copy the dll's over for unit testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You must check out configuration settings by just right clicking on your solution name and click on "Configuration Manager"
It will open a pop up window for Configuration Manager.
Check not for the platform your projects are using it is better to choose any CPU.
Hope this can help.Give it a try:)
Because thats what your exeception says as you have quoted
Thanks

Comment: The problem is not related to build configuration, it is related to visual studio(?) trying to load `native dll's` and expecting them to be `.net assemblies`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to repro this issue and found that the root cause is that you have set your test project to be compiled as !AnyCpu. Is there any particular reason why you would want this for managed test code?

So unless you change this you will continue to see this message.

If you want to continue using this configuration for your test project you would need to update your .testsettings file as suggested in the message.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but the issue is not related to the c# assemblies. it is related to the native dll's that get called using `PInvoke`. The .net assemblies are build with AnyCPU (nothing special).

Comment: Right thats what I tried too. So its pretty odd that you are seeing this warning on your native dlls. Since we did not have pure native UTs in 2010. It would have been easier if I could get your repro.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry if this seems remedial. I am including it for the sake of completeness.

#### General library behavior

A library can be referenced either in the project file (and so the compiler injects to code to load the references) or dynamically at runtime with LoadLibrary() or PInvoke calls. When a referenced library is loaded, a function at the entry point is run can in turn load any libraries it depends on. When loading the library, there is a well-known set of paths that Windows will search, including `%WINDIR%\Assembly` and the current directory. There's a lot of good conceptual information on [Wikipedia about this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29). I recommend reading it.

#### Possible Root Causes

I can't tell from your question if you are having trouble building the application, building the tests, or executing either. Generally I would not expect PInvoke to cause compile errors.

1. **Error during app build:** VS generally will show you that you have a reference to a DLL it can't find. However, you may be missing a DLL that is needed to satisfy all the dependencies. To resolve, just add the reference to the missing DLL. (This is the simplest issue, so I'm guessing this isn't what you're seeing.)
2. **Error during test build:** Since your test will reference your application/library, it also needs to have the same reference. Usually the easiest way to ensure you are getting everything is to remove all references and add a reference to the project you are testing. It's possible you some additional libraries are necessary for some tests, but not your app/lib itself. These need to be added separately.
3. **Error during app execution:** This can happen when starting the application, or later when an call to the external library is made if late binding is used.
4. **Error during test execution:** This can happen the same as with app execution. However, tests can also be "partially built" to only execute a small number of tests. In these cases, some files may not be copied. Using the `[DeploymentItem()]` attribute, you can specify that a test requires the presence of certain files in the test or app/lib project to function. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.deploymentitemattribute%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) describes how this can be done.

#### Resolution

For #1 & #2 the solution lies in adjusting the references in the project.
For #3 & #4, it may get trickier. There is a similar question to yours regarding Windows Mobile [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456093/cant-find-pinvoke-dll-error-in-windows-mobile) which you may find useful, especially referring to using `dumpbin` to list out library dependencies. You can also use [`procmon`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) from [SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals) to monitor file access during compile or load to see which files are not found. Then you can either include the missing file, or remove the library referencing it.

Good luck. Hope this helps.

Comment: how is this answer related to the question?

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ - The attribute affects the compilation. Have you tried adding [DeploymentItem("some.dll")] for the test case throwing the error?

Comment: the problem is not with the c# projects. The problem is that Visual Studio tries to load non .net dll's, and throwing an error when they are not .net .dll's. I would like to prevent Visual Studio from trying to load the .dll's period.

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ - if you're using a library with a reference to the DLL you can't prevent it from being loaded. It doesn't matter if they are .Net DLLs or not. Is this an MSTS issue or a general compile issue? Might help if you clarified the question.

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ - When you reference another library (either with PInvoke or as a .Net DLL) the library will try and load all it's dependencies. If one is not found, execution will fail with the message you mentioned. The only way to prevent it is to a) remove the library reference in the project or b) remove the PInvoke call that is loading the library. I'll update the answer with some links on general DLL reference info.