# Porting embedded Dll from eVC to VS2008 causes not finding dll

Tags: memory, compiler-construction, embedded, global-variables, porting

I am trying to port an unmanaged C++ Dll from one embedded device to another and am facing some strange problems which I think must have something to do with memorymanagement and/or compilers. I am not posting much code but describe what I tried as I have tried too many different things to post all code and I think the problem must be somewhere deeper within.

The first device is running WinCE 5.0 and is compiled using embedded Visual C++ 4.0.
The second device is running Windows Embedded Compact 7 (I will call it WinCE 7 for simplicity) and is compiled using VS2008. Both devices have their own SDKs designed for the boards.

On the first device the Dll is running without any problems, but on the second device the with ne new SDK compiled Dll is not working. Having a C# applikation on the second device I tryed PInvoke to access the dll but on the PInvoke line in Debug Mode got the error message:

> Can't find PInvoke DLL NAME.dll

[After some research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456093/cant-find-pinvoke-dll-error-in-windows-mobile) I learnd this error can have differend causes:

1. Missing dependencies of the native library you are calling into.
2. The native assmebly was compiled for the wrong subsystem (i.e. desktop, not CE)
3. The native assembly was compiled for the wrong processor (i.e. x86 and not ARM)
4. Not enough virtual memory for the DLL to load.

I used peinfo to check the dll. All dependencies are being found on the device, it is compiled for WinCE 7 and the processor type is right. (I would have been surprised if not, using the right SDK) So there still is number 4: not enough virtual memory. But WinCE5 is limited to 32MB virtual memory and running while WinCE7 can have up to 2GB?
So I started to try some things to narrow the error in and will tell you my results.

First I took my dll compiled for the first device and tryed to use it on the second device. Surprisingly the .net application can find and PInvoke this one. But some functions inside the Dll don't seem to be running right so I guess I have to use the right SDK. But having the right code for both dll I know the exports must be right. I am aware the two compilers use different c++ name mangling styles so that is not the problem, too.

Next I wrote a simple c++ application on VS2008 using the new SDK to Load the Dll from there. On the first device the application runs this way but now on my remote Display on running on the second device I get the Error Message:

> Unable to import library NAME.dll ! Program will exit.

At least now I know it has nothing to do with .net and PInvoke. But further on I made a simple new dll using VS2008 and the new SDK and ne .net application is able to PInvoke it. So there must be something in the code that doesn't like to be Loaded. :-/

After some hours of searching through the code I realised the system doesn't like some global variables. I know global variables are bad and I would be glad if they wouldn't be there, but I have not started the code and over the years they got more and more before me dealing with it, so they would be very hard to erase right now.

These globals are instances of classes. Some of them seem to be bad, some others seem to be ok. Confusingly they all are instances of classes and I don't know why there are good and bad ones. When I comment out the bad globals, the application is able to PInvoke the Dll. One of the bad globals is enough to make to applikation not find the Dll.

Why is it like this using VS2008 with WinCE 7 but not using eVC4.0 with WinCE 5? And what is the problem with the globals? How can I solve this problem? At best the same code should be working for both compilers but first I need some ideas, what is wrong with the second compiler.

Comment: Can you figure out (at least on the working system) how big the memory footprint ends up being, and if some of it is wasted?  Can you experimentally cut out parts until it works, and thus discover which part is the problem?   Can you somehow get a debugger in there and track the loading process to determine the point of failure?

Comment: On the working WinCE 5 system about 20mb of the 32mb virtual memory are beeing used. I tried cutting out parts and came to the globals this way. Some of them seem to cause the problem but stripping down the classes beeing instantiated as globals didn't clearify why. 
There is not much left in them but a few

Comment: There is not much left in them but a few basic membervariables. When some of them are beeing cut out it works...
On some point I could add an integer membervariable to make it work but it did not work without the integer... so it is very confusing for me.

Comment: For testing I capsulated the globals into a singleton class. The Programm exist when intantiating this singleton class throwing "Error:

A native exception has occurred in Multiserver.exe. Select Quit and then restart this program, or select details for more information."
Details: "Error
ExceptionCode: 0x80000002
ExceptionAddress: 0x4382a214
Fault module: NAME.dll
Offset: 0x0001a214"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my Dll loading problem. The two systems have a different behaviour on #pragma pack. So eventually there was missalignment while loading the dll what made the dll crash. Because of the globals it was in the loading process of the dll, so the error message did not say something about missalignment but the standard "Can't find PInvoke DLL".